# Augmenting data structure for matrix

Tags: arrays, data-structures, time-complexity

Given a square matrix of size n (data structure) with operation as follow

```
read(i,j) returns the element
write(i,j,x) write the new element 
initalize() set matrix to zero
```

and the read and write are performed in (worst case) constant time.
How can I augment it so that the following operations performed in (worst case) constant time?

```
emptyrow(i) if the ith row is empty then return true
emptycol(j) if the jth col is empty then return true
```

My first thought is that I don't need to augment. I can simply use a for loop and read(i,j) to get my result, and at worst case will just be constant time n. Am I on the right track or I still need to somehow augment the data structure. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider storing the data structure as an n × n matrix for the entries, plus two extra arrays: a rowCount array counting how many 1s are in each row of the matrix, and a colCount array containing how many 1s are in each column of the array.

To perform an initialize() operation, you create the matrix and the rowCount / colCount arrays and initialize everything to 0. This takes time O(n<sup>2</sup>). To perform a read(i, j), just read from the matrix in time O(1). To perform a write(i, j, x), write x to position (i, j), and if you changed a 0 to 1 or a 1 to 0, make the appropriate increments/decrements of the rowCount and colCount arrays. This also takes time O(1). Finally, to perform emptyRow(i) or emptyCol(j), just return whether rowCount[i] or colCount[j], respectively, is zero. This also takes time O(1).

You could speed up to construction O(1) if you use hash tables for everything and treat "empty" to mean 0, though you now have average-case O(1) guarantees for the remaining operations rather than worst-case guarantees. Depending on the circumstances, that might be a good trade-off.